# How to create a JMS destination with exactly two subscribers?

Tags: java, ejb, jms

we have to application servers, both reading from the same JMS server, preferably from the same destination. We want to make sure that every message put into this destination is read by exactly two listeners - our idea was a Topic with **exactly** two durable subscribers.

We are using JBoss 5.1.0. How can I:

1) write a *-service.xml so that I can be sure that this message is read by two (no less no more) subscribers before it's deleted from destination

2) write a MDB using EJB3.0 specs (with annotations and stuff) that'll connect to the topic as one of the two durable subscribers?

I know that I can create a subscriber and then subscribe to a topic but that doesn't assures me that the messages put into topic before subscription will be delivered to me. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't help you with writing code (im a c# guy) I have had a similar requirement. I ended up bridging from the topic to 2 queues and the receivers both consumed from their individual queue rather than the topic.

Comment: I actually had a similar solution in mind, but not with a topic, but simple queue and MDB which would read a message, clone it, and send it to both queues. Will have to check if this is acceptable in our project.

Comment: You dont need to write code to do this. I am sure JBoss has bridging built in, you just specify the source and destination and it does the leg work for you.

Comment: Yes, JBoss has the bridging thing, but this mechanism seems to work 1-to-1 and I would want to set it 1-to-2 - friend suggested making two bridges, one for each recieving queue, but bridge seems to consume the message after forwarding it (so message would go either through one bridge or second one, but not through both).

Comment: if you have 2 bridges from the same topic to 2 queues then both queues will receive the message.

Comment: hmm.. you're right - and bridges would be set up at the same time as the topic, so there will be no messages lost at startup. Thanks ^^